# Is it ok to drink green tea when having mononucleosis?

Tags: diet, tea, mononucleosis

The coffee and alcohol are not recommended for people who have mononucleosis.
But what about tea. More concretely, how about **green tea**? Are there any recommendations about that?

Comment: Could you provide some sources regarding "not recommended for people who have"? This actually seems like a reasonable question, but you should provide us some sources that back up your initial claims.